# Jquery Selectors - a Class inside a Each

Tags: jquery, class, this, selector, each

I have a loop of Inputs with a class atribute called guestline and im Trying to figure out if a input field is filled or not checking its class, but im stuck with the selector.

```
      $("div#acompanhantes div.acompanhante").each(function(i){
            if($(this).next('.guestline').val() != '') {
                alert()
            }
            else {
                var fn = (vagasdispo > i ) ? 'show' : 'hide';
                $(this)[fn]();
            }


        });
```

The Html is

```
     <div id='acompanhante_1' class='acompanhante'>
<h3>1o. acompanhante </h3>

<div class="form-group"><label for="Invited1Name" class="control-label col-md-3">Nome</label>

    <div class="col-md-8"><input name="data[Invited][1][name]" class="guestline guestline_1 form-control"
                                 maxlength="250" type="text" id="Invited1Name"/></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group"><label for="Invited1Phone1" class="control-label col-md-3">Telefone de Contato</label>

    <div class="col-md-8"><input name="data[Invited][1][phone_1]" class="validate[required] large form-control"
                                 type="text" id="Invited1Phone1"/></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group"><label for="Invited1Document1" class="control-label control-label col-md-3">Número do
    documento de identidade</label>

    <div class="col-md-8"><input name="data[Invited][1][document_1]" class="validate[required] large form-control"
                                 maxlength="255" type="text" id="Invited1Document1"/></div>
</div>
<div class=""><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="hidden" name="data[Invited][1][special_needs]"
                                                    id="Invited1SpecialNeeds_" value="0"/><input type="checkbox"
                                                                                                 name="data[Invited][1][special_needs]"
                                                                                                 colname="special_needs"
                                                                                                 value="1"
                                                                                                 id="Invited1SpecialNeeds"/>Portador
    de Necessidade Especial </label></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find` instead of `next`

```
 if($(this).find('.guestline').val() != '') {
```

Answer (score 1):

The input is a descendant of the `acompanhante` element not a next sibling element so use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
if($(this).find('.guestline').val() != '') {
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
var EmptyFields = $(".form-group :text[value='']");
if(EmptyFields.length > 0){
    alert('Please fill in all the text fields!');
    EmptyFields.addClass('error');
}else{
    $(".form-group .error").removeClass('error');
}
```

or

```
$(".form-group :text").each(function(){
    if($(this).is("[value='']")){
        $(this).addClass('error');
        alert('this field is empty: '+$(this).attr('name'));
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass("error");

    }
});
```